# How to stop h2o from saving massive .ERR, .OUT and other log files to the local drive

Tags: r, logging, h2o

I am currently running a script in which several h2o glm and deeplearning models are being generated for several iterations of a Monte-Carlo Cross-Validation. When finished running (which takes about half a day), h2o is saving immense files to the local drive (with sizes up to 8.5 GB). These files are not erased when RStudio or my computer is restarted (as I originally thought). Is there a way to stop h2o from saving these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start H2O with `h2o.init()` from R, the stdout and stderr files should be saved to a temporary directory (see R's `tempdir()` to see the path).  This temporary directory should be removed when the R session exits.  It seems as though this is not working with RStudio, however it works if you are using R from the command line.  I'm not sure if this is a setting that can be changed in RStudio or if this is an RStudio bug.

But you can take more control yourself.  You can start H2O by hand using java on the command line and then connect from R using `h2o.init()`.

```
java -Xmx5g -jar h2o.jar
```

In this example, I started H2O with 5 GB of Java heap memory, but you should increase that if your data is larger.  Then connecting in R will look like this:

```
> h2o.init()
 Connection successful!

R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
    H2O cluster uptime:         16 hours 34 minutes 
    H2O cluster version:        3.15.0.99999 
    H2O cluster version age:    17 hours and 25 minutes  
    H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_me_exn817 
    H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
    H2O cluster total memory:   4.43 GB 
    H2O cluster total cores:    8 
    H2O cluster allowed cores:  8 
    H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
    H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
    H2O Connection port:        54321 
    H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
    H2O Internal Security:      FALSE 
    H2O API Extensions:         XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, Core V4 
    R Version:                  R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
```

So if you want to redirect both stdout and stderr to devnull you simply add the redirect command to the end of the java command to start the H2O cluster and connect to H2O from R again.  To redirect both stderr and stdout, you append `> /dev/null 2>&1` like this:

```
java -Xmx5g -jar h2o.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Tom, can you update your answer with how to tell H2O to redirect this output to devnull so the files are not created in the first place?

Comment: Erin, this would be the preferred option in my use case. I am not sure what I am doing differently, but the .OUT file (which is the real source of the storage issues) is not removed when my session exits.

Comment: @jhearn I have updated the post to include instructions on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks guys. I am not sure that the additional dev/null statement is necessary, however, as the files in question are not created when started from cmd. That said, Tom's original solution works just fine, and serves as a nice BandAid until I address the underlying RStudio-linked problem.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this in a spark shell running H2O. The shell had 50 executors connected and this caused the `/tmp` directories on those nodes to eventually cause storage issues.

When `h2o.init()` is called it creates jvm's. The logging from h2o is handled by these jvm's. But when the shell is shutdown those jvm's persist and just log heartbeat errors in `/tmp` in perpetuity. You will need to find the jvm's associated with h2o and shut them down. I believe in my case the specific process names where `water.H2OApp`

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to take care of the problem by removing those files after running every model.

```
unlink(list.files(tempdir(), full.names = TRUE), recursive = TRUE)
```

This helps remove the temporary files when I run the multiple models in a loop.